# What $\tt h'*h$ means? (where $h=[w_0 \ w_1 \ w_2 \ \ldots]$ are the filter tap weights)

Tags: matlab, filters

I know `conv(h,h)` means $H(z)*H(z)$, but is `h'*h` mean $H(z)*H(z)$? Or integral of it, why? Or what other thing it is?

```
h=[w0; w1; w2; ...]
```

Comment: If `h` is a column vector then `h'*h` means a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) (inner product) of the vector `h` with itself. This, in turn, is equal to the squared L2 norm of a vector.

Comment: @jojek L2 norm means sqrt(E)?

Comment: What's E? L2 norm of vector `h` is defined as `sqrt(h'*h)`.

Comment: E means energy, how h'*h=sqrt(h'*h)?

Comment: The `h'*h` does not involve the `sqrt` operation. It's just the sum of squares.

Comment: But I think it invole `^2` instead.I want it's DSP aspect, is that energy of $H(Z)$?

Comment: no need to use capital $Z$!

Answer (score 4):

If
$$
h = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 
w_0\\
w_1\\
\vdots\\
w_{N-1}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Then `h'*h` is just
$$
h^T h = \left[ w_0\ w_1\ \cdots \ w_{N-1} \right ]  \left[ \begin{array}{c} 
w_0\\
w_1\\
\vdots\\
w_{N-1}
\end{array}
\right]\\
= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} w_n^2
$$

So it is just the "energy" in $h$.

Comment: Nice, but isn't that mean: $H(z)∗H(z)$? Or I think integral of it is energy, isn't that?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd I'm not quite sure what you mean? Writing $h^Th$ is just a shorthand way of writing the squared sum of the entries. I can't find a quick relationship with $H(z)$, though I suspect something like the integral of $H^*(z)H(z) = |H(z)|^2$ around the unit circle might do it, as per [Parseval's theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) Note: here $H^*(z)$ means the complex conjugate of $H(z)$.